# The maximum image size one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

The maximum image size one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB, unlike what is stated:

[image]

Comment: Two men in black can still be heavy...

Comment: how do you find that it's 2 MiB, not 2 MB?

Comment: “MB” means 1048576 bytes. It isn't the SI prefix, it's the computerese prefix. Deal with it.

Comment: @Gilles I think it is fairer to say: MB is ambiguous and overloaded, and has variously been used to represent **all of** 1000x1000, 1024x1000 and 1024x1024 bytes - usually depending on which sounds more marketable. Conversely, however, MiB is still meaningless to the majority of non IT folk.

Comment: @Ooker I can confirm: `public const int MaxUploadSizeBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; that is unnecessarily ambiguous (although since MB is so poorly defined, historically, we could argue that it isn't actually *wrong* as such). But: this should be clarified in the next build.

Comment: what's your plan on the next build? Also, have a look at [Why can't this picture be uploaded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261962/260800)

Comment: @Ooker : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261962/why-cant-this-picture-be-uploaded#comment854284_261962

Comment: [The issue is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328796/178179)