# Why can't this picture be uploaded from URL?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

http://www.litaniasports.com/facility/documents/00396-009%20Wave%20Bike%20Rack.jpg

I can't come up any idea why this picture cannot be added by uploading from URL. The file size is over 1.6 MB a little bit, so it is much less than the max of 2 MB.

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/245360

Comment: Looks like it was created by some fancy software, in the raw response I see "Adobe Photoshop CS3 Windows", and this format is simply not supported by imgur, which tries to analyze the picture.

Comment: It still seems a regular JPG to me. @ShadowWizard

Comment: That error happens inside imgur; as such, I can't tell you what *specifically* it doesn't like (the error message is fairly generic) - as @ShadowWizard notes: presumably there is an encoding option in use that imgur doesn't like. Options: 1) imgur change their API to allow the format; 2) you re-save the file to tweak the encoding; 2 seems like a more timely fix

Comment: Agree with @Marc that this probably isn't worth spending much time on, unless we'll see this happening more.

Comment: @MarcGravell "the issue seems to be on the **SE's imgur interface** where some kinda URL validation (and/or filename check) is happening before the image upload" - quoted HackerKarma below

Comment: @Ooker SE's imgur interface from where the API sends the data to imgur... I would like to see what the endpoint respone looks like... we need to look into base64 + url encoding which is causing the wrong interpretation of the final url

Comment: @Ooker I'll take another look

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree the response is generic... i know you guys are super busy but please look into the response header .... like I said in the above comment

Comment: @HackerKarma `<error><message>Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.</message>...`; I'm checking something, though

Comment: @HackerKarma your comment isn't clear, but if you work for imgur ("we need to look into", etc), feel free to ping me at `marc@stackoverflow.com`, and we can talk more - but I'm not going to dump the raw http (including keys, etc) here ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Appreciated. If that's what imgur sending then they must be striping out all other data like "parameters:, request:, type:, method:, success:.... etc. I think we have to look into the "CONFIG" options that API gets.... base64 encoding ...

Comment: @HackerKarma some of that is there - not the base-64, but I have a hunch...

Comment: @MarcGravell I just posted another comment. Hope that is clear. Oh no no, I don't expect to dump that data either. Thanks for the email. I don't work for imgur but they do have a support for API and have submitted the case. Lets' see what their support team says. I will forward it you

Comment: @MarcGravell do you have moment to chat? Comments warnings are coming to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/907/discussion-between-marc-gravell-and-hackerkarma).

Comment: To confirm: looks like I am wrong and this is our fault; we should be able to fix it soon

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the chat and HOT FIX!

Comment: could someone eli5 this for me? Thanks

Comment: @Ooker what made you think of un-accepting my answer

Comment: @HackerKarma erm, idk. Marc's answer has more jargon than yours XD

Comment: @Ooker Please read my chat conversation with Marc... and Marc is actually giving [status-completed] reason i.e. the bug that caused this. Otherwise every [status-completed] message by SE team will be treated as a "official" answer. Our findings will be useless. Anyway, you're OP and you have right to select the right answer. I will have to live with it.

Comment: @HackerKarma oh, I thought that you are joking. Sorry about that. Anyway, I have already read your chat and I don't know a thing. I thought that Marc's answer is the final consensus so that's why I accept that. I have moved the accept tick.

Comment: No problem. It's happens. At least you went back and read the chat. But, there are some users, who don't even do that. They just see the official ♦ mod answer and upvote. Do you see how much research it took to answer right. I worked hard for this debugging, reading imgur API pages and chatting with Marc. It was almost 2 hours of work. And Marc did confirmed it by saying "To confirm: looks like I am wrong and this is our fault; we should be able to fix it soon".

Comment: @HackerKarma no, I'm not the one who accept everything the diamonds say without thinking. It's just I have thought that you two have made a consensus, and that's written in his answer. I have thought your joke under his comment is the evidence for that. Sorry for making you feel unfair.

Comment: @Ooker. No, I am not targeting you either. The official ♦ mod answer and upvotes, as far as my answer goes, and in general. How many of those upvoters do you think read my answer, comments, conversation with Marc. If they did then why am I left with 2 votes (excluding your's). That's why that joke but [status-completed] was my takeaway. But, since I worked so hard for this answer, I felt little sad to see your un-acceptance.  And, that was it, nothing against you. You're fine. Comments are getting lengthy so its my last comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has something to do with Stack Exchange's imgur upload interface. May be the file resize algorithm (ShadowWizard's comment below), file encoding settings, etc that goes while analyzing the image before the actual upload. I just uploaded the OP's suggested image by visiting to http://www.imgur.com and used "enter image URLs" option to upload the image.

Here is the [direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj4b2.jpg) to uploaded image using "**enter image URLs**" at imgur:

`![Direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj4b2.jpg)`

> [image]

Here is the same above image added by uploading from URL using "**SE's imgur interface**":

> [image]

Now, here is some food for thought. Upon doing further investigation on few things such as:

1. Source site blocking imgur from accessing
2. Imgur blocking/banning the source site
3. Invalid image type
4. URL format of the image without any special chars in it (especially in the "file name")

As far as the first three points goes, there is no issue at all. My first two screenshots voids all those first 3 points. So, the next thing left was to try and upload images from the same source with proper file name.

Here I am uploading `http://www.litaniasports.com/images/stadium.jpg` using SE's imgur file uploader: (works perfectly!)

> [image]

Now, I tried another image (from the same source) with a special char %20 i.e. a space in it  `http://www.litaniasports.com/facility/documents/830901%20Closed.jpg`

and it throws the following **error**: (as said by OP)

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

So, the problem is ***not*** about the file type or its format, it has something to do with the **special char** i.e. ***%20* (a space)** in the image filename. The special character (%20) in the image filename has no issue when you do a direct web-upload (by entering image URL) on the imgur.com website. So, the issue seems to be on the SE's imgur interface where some kinda URL validation (and/or filename check) is happening before the image upload.

That's what I can think here. Please share your thoughts or any additional findings.

Comment: True, that's likely because the resize algorithm that imgur is trying to use on behalf of Stack Exchange, which fails for some reason for that specific picture.

Answer (score 14):

The reason for that is because the .NET `Uri` class has a distressing habit of not quite retaining what you put into it ;p In the next build, we have circumvented this glitch, and the url you show above now works fine - as do other URLs.

Comment: you're stealing all my +1's :) No issue... [status-completed] is the biggest upvote for me and my contribution to SE.

Comment: lol, R.I.P my glorious theory... :-D

Comment: This is not fair at all... I can understand the votes but un-accepting answer that was right is very demoralizing. I worked hard for this debugging, reading imgur API pages and chatting to Marc Gravell: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/907/discussion-between-marc-gravell-and-hackerkarma

Comment: @ShadowWizard what glorious theory?

Comment: @HackerKarma that the problem is in imgur's code

Comment: @HackerKarma why not fair? You should know the risks when answering bug reports.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't get it... To confirm: looks like I am wrong and this is our fault; we should be able to fix it soon –  quote Marc Gravell

Comment: @Hacker imgur is not part of Stack Exchange just provides the image hosting and API (if you got more questions or comments I can help with, please hit me on chat let's not flood poor Marc here :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard read my comment above. I will leave this up to Marc to clarify.

Comment: @HackerKarma: Your answer certainly deserves upvotes, but the *accepted* answer should be the one that answers the question most clearly and definitively. For bug reports, that usually means an answer from the SE devs saying that they've fixed (or will fix, or will not fix) the bug. Don't take it personally; just enjoy the rep from the upvotes, and live with the fact that the +15 rep from getting accepted is likely temporary.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Appreciated. But, in some cases, if you know the API then you can point the bug which in this case was "URL wrapping/encoding/validation". In fact, Marc and I had a chat (after our comments got lengthy)  on this. Anyway, no worries.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>In all the irony . . .</sub>

[image]

I just saved the file and uploaded it again. You could do the same yourself.

Comment: So the URL upload doesn't work. The picture upload does.

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's an issue with their server. BTW @Patrick is this kinda answer acceptable? I did show the solution/showed more precisely where a possible bug is. . .

Comment: Don't know. In my opinion it should just be fixed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's SE's imgur upload doesn't work. See my answer below

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M No, it's not a server issue... please see my answer.