# Will the other person get alerted when it says "let's start this conversation in chat"?

Tags: discussion, chat

If me and somebody else are in comment and they get along and it says to create a chat, and so I click that link and it makes a comment from me saying "Let us continue this discussion in chat.", and I can type in there, but I can't do @ his name.

And I see that that link is saying "let us continue" doesn't have @ and his name either. Is that person going to get pinged? About the comment saying "let us continue.." or with my message in the chat?

Because if not, then I should probably make another comment afterwards saying "^^^" pointing to that chat link.

Comment: I got a notification when someone did this to me earlier.

Comment: @Catija can you screenshot the comment "let's start this conversation in chat" and screenshot its associated notification? and  I would then accept it as an answer

Comment: @barlop Here is my [chat link from Marc Gravell](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261962/why-cant-this-picture-be-uploaded-from-url?noredirect=1#comment854312_261962) and I have a notification of it in my inbox.

Comment: @HackerKarma  I see the chat link. Can you paste a screenshot of the notification on imgur, and link to it? (So I can see what the notification looks like).  I will accept an answer with that.

Comment: @barlop added in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [**chat link**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261962/why-cant-this-picture-be-uploaded-from-url?noredirect=1#comment854312_261962) that I received from Marc Gravell ♦ moderator on the post "[Why can't this picture be uploaded from URL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261962/why-cant-this-picture-be-uploaded-from-url)":

> Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261962/why-cant-this-picture-be-uploaded-from-url?noredirect=1#comment854312_261962). –  Marc Gravell ♦ Aug 3 at
>   15:38

And here is the screenshot of the corresponding inbox notification

> [image]

Comment: For clarity: You were *not* the only other participant in the comments at that point, nor the post owner.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Post owner is "Ooker" (you can see it on post) and Marc Gravell sent me the chat request and upon clicking I was the only one chatting with him

Comment: Yeah, but I was referring to the fact that there's no other way you would have been notified normally.

Comment: @NathanTuggy All I know that I got an inbox notification (as shown in the screenshot) and tme comment message was there. I guess Marc Gravell would be the best person to ask.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  Not sure what you mean, since  obviously no one person is the only participant in comments that spawn a chat, it takes two for that to happen.  And why do you state as fact that there's no toher way he would've been notified normally.. what do you mean by normally and how does that differ from this case.  The fact that he's not the owner and sitll got a chat link just bolsters his case more.

Comment: @barlop: I said "only *other*". I said that because there are three ways normally for a comment to notify you: a direct ping, it's your post being commented on, or you're the only other participant, *along with whoever just commented*. I was proving what had previously been implied.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  You wrote "You were not the only other participant in the comments "    and you wrote re getting notified "you're the only other participant, along with whoever just commented"     What do you mean he is not the only other participant, if you're proving what he had implied, and you're trying to argue that he got notified for being "the only other participant, along with whoever just commented".   What is the difference in the meaning of your words in being "the only other participant", vs "the only other participant along with the person that had just commented"?

Comment: @barlop: There is no difference in the two descriptions, since the second adds a dependent clause to explain what the first already referred to. If I repeat myself in different words, it's to clarify my meaning, since I very seldom contradict myself. The implication being proven is "yes, the other person will get alerted" (directly answering your question in the affirmative), and the only way to prove that is to show that no other known existing code path for notification will cause the observed behavior, and that therefore the chat message must. This is the fundamental diagnostic technique.

Comment: @NathanTuggy   It is impossible4 A to be1 of the "other participant(s)", because if he was they wouldn't be other.   And if A had  a participant,then no 1 person would b the only participant.  So u talking about being not the only other participant is a very odd formulation.But yes I understand the diagnostic procedure / what you're getting at.Bizarre terms tho 'cos if A was alone I suppose he'd still be not the only other participant, because he's not even the "other" participant.n if A had a participant, then he'd still b not the only other participant because he's not the other participant