# Could we support WebP image format when uploading images?

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

SE is a leading example of top multimedia streamlining for ease of use.

[WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) is currently unsupported when attempting to upload an image. It's fast becoming a very common image format because it is superior to other formats in various ways.

If `.webp` becomes useable on SE it could be a good upgrade for the future.

As of 2023, usage has doubled from 3 to 7%, especially on top 1000 websites [of which 14% use WebP](https://w3techs.com/technologies/comparison/im-jpeg,im-webp).

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can upload them directly to Imgur.com, but that [has other problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-2023-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stack-exc) ...

Comment: No, it is not very common. And SE does not host the images themselves, it's imgur, and SE will have to pay them extra (likely very much money) to add such a thing. I don't think it's worth it, better spend on more useful things.

Comment: Anyhow, uploading directly to imgur isn't a good idea. The image will rot within a while, and lost forever. Better convert to standard format, and upload in the usual way. There are lots of free and very fast online converters, simple to use.

Comment: @shadowthespring since when have you used the internet? ... https://jakegroup.com/blog/the-rise-of-webp/ ... chrome has adopted it as a standard "How to get around Chrome's new save-as-WebP image format issue" ... quote: .... WebP, an image format developed by Google, which is intended to replace JPEG, PNG, and GIF file formats, will soon be generated by default... ... Why would wordpress merge it into core by default if it's not very common?

Comment: quote: Because starting from May 2021, Google search will use website speed as a ranking factor. The smaller the images on a website in KiloBytes, the faster they will show on a slow Internet connection. So, if your website loads fast, Google will rank you higher! (Allegedly)

Comment: It takes me 20 minutes to add a new file format encoder when to my apps, so I thought that was perhaps easy for SE, handy if chrome and other programs encode it by default to 30% of image space, for a site like Wikipedia that's 30% less bandwidth. However I have compression compute requirement and compression repeatability degradation suspicions about webp. https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webp_study

Comment: No. I started using the internet 23 years ago, and first time I bumped into a .webp image was around 10 years ago, totally by chance when downloading something and baffled by that strange extension. Anyway, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE5q6.png) proves my point. 7.6% is by no means "common", very far from it. It's nice, there's niche of people who like it, all good. But please, don't use wrong terms and change the truth just to advance what you ask for.

Comment: @bandybabboon adding support to an app used by a few people and adding it to a site used by a few *million* people are *not* quite the same thing. You can drop the support practically whenever, imgur will have to keep it alive even when Google decides to ditch it like it ditched JPEG2000.

Comment: webp supports animations and is orders of magnitude smaller than gifs for that purpose. Supporitng webp would allow much higher quality animations under the 2MB limit than is currently possible.

Comment: The place I've seen webp most is on Discord: For some reason, if you upload an emoji as a png, and then try to re-download the file, it defaults to downloading a webp file. Regardless, I've never liked webp because it's supported by approximately zero offline image editors.

Comment: I think reddit has made some sort of switch too. I've noticed recent image downloads downloading .webp files.

Comment: @muru The usage has doubled to 14% of high traffic websites this year, I've edited the post to provide usage information for the format from 2023.

Comment: @bandybabboon which makes no difference whatsoever to my point

Comment: @muru It's an open-source standard so why would you be worried about it losing support like jpeg2000 did, which was designed in 2000 when the average computer featured around 64 MB of memory, webp won't have the same problem today when 15 dollar computers have 512gb and phones have 1-2 gb. that's  10,000+ times more memory... It's safe to bet that 50% of websites will use webp by 2028 because it saves 30% bandwidth, and adoption is doubling yearly.

Comment: JPEG 2000 failed because computers had 20,000 times less RAM in those times... We need a new standard given that RAM is unlimited on cellphone bandwidth, the limitor is 100% transfer speeds these days, not RAM. JPEG is designed for low memory computing.

Comment: @bandybabboon "open source" doesn't mean that it magically gets supported. The developers of the browsers and websites need to support it, like you're asking for in this very question. The rest of what you wrote seems to be pure gibberish.