# Rules on use of handles within a post, for instance attempting to target a particular user

Tags: discussion

I edited out a handle from someone else's [post on Chem SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167360/adiabatic-venting-of-propane-tank/167418#167418).
The self-answer in the post opened with

> Attention @Poutnik: Since I have not yet received any answers to my question, I will post the answer ...

I removed the opening call to attention.

Here the OP seems to want to use the post to continue or open a discussion with user Poutnik, but tbh motives are not fully clear. The post seems ok (useful) in other regards.

Although fairly innocuous my assumption was that such directly targeted messaging within Q or As  is generally frowned upon (regardless of whether they work or not as desired). I'm guessing the edit is not just ok but good practice.

What is best practice here?

Comment: Yea, I'd say just edit it out. It's not useful, it's noise.

Comment: Well, sometimes it might be valid in response to comments asking to clarify, but in that case you brought it's useless indeed.

Comment: I'd be careful trying to create objective rules about how to handle handles. I do this all the time - not to force someone's attention, usually to acknowledge / thank, but that is dangerously subjective IMHO. [I did it yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391417/165455), and that is arguably borderline.

Answer (score 8):

The at symbol (@) can be used within comments to ping other users who are participating in that Q&A by prefacing their name.

However, doing the same in a question or answer post does not do that i.e. it initiates no action.  If it looks like they are using it to try and draw attention to their post then I think you should edit it out.

Be aware that many users mention (without trying to ping) other users and using the at symbol makes it clear that the characters which follow are a username.

Comment: Thanks, I tried narrowing the Q. The OP is probably unaware that handles do not work when used within a post. The OP wants to address a particular user, as you mention in the end of your answer, but does so in a rather stark way that suggests the post is intended almost exclusively for the other user.

Comment: @BuckThorn so you can comment under the answer with something like "To draw the attention of [name here] please comment under one of their posts, linking to your own answer".

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Yes, that would explain to the OP correct usage of handles. The question here however is about whether targeting questions to particular users is ok (in this case I have narrowed the question to using a handle by which I mean at username, but might at the risk of my question losing clarity include just username). BTW I realize I may have just inverted the emphasis of my Q just now to targeting from using handles. But I guess the targeting part is important.

Comment: @BuckThorn Every post is available to everyone so attempting to "target" someone within it is pointless chitchat that should be edited out.

Comment: It's also worth noting that sometimes folks without enough reputation for the commenting privilege will sometimes post "answers" that attempt to comment on/respond to another answer.