# The maximum image size that one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

The maximum image size one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB, unlike what is stated:

[image]

The issue was [fixed on ~Aug 3 '15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261975/178179) but came back (and I cannot remove the `status-completed` tag, hence this new question).

Comment: While MiB is unambiguously power-of-2 megabytes, MB is ambiguous and, depending on context, could mean power-of-10 (traditional) or power-of-2 (Microsoft terminology).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We just pushed a build that fixes this...again. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Is the limit now 2 MB or 2 MiB? I'd prefer being able to upload 2097152-byte images rather than 2000000-byte ones.

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica that'd be much more convenient [if the image uploader could  automatically resize (or change compression) to the largest image possible, or close to it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273986/178179). Manually doing so results in a lot of collective time wasted.

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica I'll point you to [Marc's comment on the origina; report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261925/the-maximum-image-size-one-can-upload-is-2-mib-not-2-mb#comment854258_261925).