# Automatically resize images if their file size is too large

Tags: feature-request, status-review, images, uploader

I posted this in 2018 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317672/174572) and it was marked as status-deferred.  It's almost three years later and this is still an issue on Gardening and Landscaping and any site where photos are used to help answer questions

The real issue with image uploading that I see all the time on SE sites where users are not technically savvy is that the size limit of 2 MB is a barrier to asking questions. Most people use cell phones to take pictures and many cannot figure out how to reduce the resolution so the picture will not exceed the size limit.

> Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MB).

Instead of showing a message that your picture could not be uploaded just show a message that your picture is being resized and automatically resize it.

Comment: Please also state why it was deffered: "Not a bad idea, but unrelated to these change. As such I'm deferring it. You might want to post this as an independent feature request. Thanks. – Joe Friend"

Comment: And while you revamp, consider [rephrasing the help center part that goes with it](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/when-help-is-not-helpful).

Comment: Also proposed in 2016 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273986/178179 and likely earlier too. Note that [the maximum image size one can upload is 2 MiB, not 2 MB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179).